# SQL - Why SELECT query has been BLOCKED by INSERT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I always thought the writers never block the readers (and vice versa).

However, what am seeing right now is very strange. I'm probably wrong and am missing something here. So please help as this is driving me crazy!

Today I created a very simple table:

```
USE [testdb]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTab](
    [N] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTab]  WITH CHECK ADD CHECK  (([n]>(10)))
GO
```

Then I populated it with a few rows.

Next I decided to set `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` to `ON` and select from the table in another session in a completely separate execution of the SQL Server Management Studio. The below snapshot demonstrates what hapened:

[image]

You see the issue? The select query is still executing! This query never returns. It returns only after I commit or rollback the insert statement. I tested the same scenario multiple times and the same thing happened over and over again.

To further confirm my observation, have a look at the below report:

[image]

Can you help and let me know what am I doing wrong?

or if my assumption that readers cannot be blocked is entirely (or partially) wrong?

Thanks!

Note: Initially I was connected as the same user as the insert session when I wanted to query the table. Once I saw my select was blocked, I decided to login and test using another user. Hence, the using as 'sa' account. :)

Comment: Posting images only discourages readers and is generally worthy of a downvote - especially for someone with SO experience/reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some research I just realized what the issue was. In SQL Server readers and writers actually do block each other sometimes. This is unlike Oracle where readers and writers never block each other.

**Further Explanation**

I am an Oracle DBA and do not know too much about SQL Server databases. My observation today came as a surprise for me because in Oracle I had never seen a select query get blocked by an insert statement, which is because as per [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/consist.htm#CNCPT1326):

> Readers and writers do not block one another in Oracle Database.
>   Therefore, while queries still see consistent data, both read
>   committed and serializable isolation provide a high level of
>   concurrency for high performance, without the need for reading
>   uncommitted data.

This is entirely different from SQL Server where [read queries may be blocked under certain circumstances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Care to elaborate on this ? Someone else might stumble over this question being in the same situation, and knowing *what* the issue is and how to solve it / avoid it could be helpful

Comment: Another way to get "around" this: if you run a `SELECT * FROM MyTab WITH (READPAST)`, then the `SELECT` statement will "skip over" (read past) any rows that are currently locked (like those being inserted from a transaction that hasn't been committed yet), and will just return all those rows that aren't locked.

Comment: @marc_s Nope, sorry, it didn't work. I just tested it. Maybe I should change my isolation level? currently it's READ_COMMITED.

Comment: From the docs:  The READPAST table hint cannot be specified when the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database option is set to ON and either of the following conditions is true:

    The transaction isolation level of the session is READ COMMITTED.
    The READCOMMITTED table hint is also specified in the query.

To specify the READPAST hint in these cases, remove the READCOMMITTED table hint if present, and include the READCOMMITTEDLOCK table hint in the query.

Answer (score 4):

Readers do not block writers (and visa-versa) in SQL Server if you turn on the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` database option. SQL Server will then use row versioning instead of locking to provide read consistency for `READ_COMMITTED` transactions, behaving similarly to the Oracle DBMS you are more familiar with.

`READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` is on by default with Azure SQL Database but not in on-prem SQL Server versions for backwards compatibility.